# How do I write raw pixel data and save as a bitmap

Tags: c++, bmp

My problem is this: I wanna try to make a white color 24bit bitmap, but everytime I write to the bmp file, it gives me white black/white stripes. i dont understand why? Maybe i skip some bytes?
If you want more information on the code just ask.

setup settings:

```
void setup_settings( ) {
 // information om billedet
 pic.infoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BMP_InfoHeader);
 pic.infoHeader.biBitCount = 24;
 pic.infoHeader.biWidth = WIDTH;  // Hoejte i pixels
 pic.infoHeader.biHeight = HEIGH; // bredte i pixels
 pic.infoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
 pic.infoHeader.biCompression = 0;
 pic.infoHeader.biSizeImage = WIDTH * HEIGH * (pic.infoHeader.biBitCount/8);
 pic.infoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
 pic.infoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
 pic.infoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
 pic.infoHeader.biClrInportant = 0;

 pic.fileHeader.bfType[0] = 'B';
 pic.fileHeader.bfType[1] = 'M';
 pic.fileHeader.bfReservered1 = pic.fileHeader.bfReservered2 = 0;
 pic.fileHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BMP_FileHeader) + pic.infoHeader.biSize;
}
```

this funktion definition for my SaveBitmapFile is:

```
int SaveBitmapFile(const std::string filename, bit24* image){
// gem filen
std::ofstream writer(FileName.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary);

if(!writer.is_open()){
    printf("Error: While Writing\n");
    return -1;
}
writer.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&pic.fileHeader), sizeof(BMP_FileHeader) );
writer.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&pic.infoHeader), sizeof(BMP_InfoHeader) );
writer.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&image[0]), pic.infoHeader.biSizeImage);
writer.close(); 

return 0;
}
```

My structures:

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct{
  uint32_t value : 24;
}bit24;
#pragma pack(0)


// Billedet
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct{
  unsigned int Width;
  unsigned int Heigh;
bit24* RGB;
}Image;
#pragma pack(0)


typedef struct {
  BMP_FileHeader fileHeader;
  BMP_InfoHeader infoHeader;
  Image data;
 }BMP_Data;
```

My source main source code:

```
// the pic is a type of BMP_Data. sorry if i this is really messy.
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){
setup_settings();

pic.data.Heigh = pic.infoHeader.biHeight;
pic.data.Width = pic.infoHeader.biWidth;

int bytesPerRGB = (pic.infoHeader.biBitCount/8);

//padded bytes?
int paddedBytes = ( pic.data.Width * bytesPerRGB) % 4;
printf("PaddedBytes: %d\n", paddedBytes);


pic.data.RGB = new bit24[ pic.data.Heigh * pic.data.Width * bytesPerRGB];

uint8_t r,g,b;
r = 0xFF;
g = 0xFF;
b = 0xFF;

/*
for( unsigned int y = 0; y < pic.data.Heigh; y++)
    for( unsigned int x = 0; x < pic.data.Width; x++)
    {
        pic.data.RGB[x + (y*pic.data.Width )].value = ( (b << 0) | (g << 8) | (r << 16) );
    } 
    */

for( unsigned int i = 0; i < pic.data.Heigh * pic.data.Width * bytesPerRGB; i+=3){
    pic.data.RGB[i ].value = ( (b << 0) | (g << 8) | (r << 16) );
}

SaveBitmapFile(FileName, pic.data.RGB);
delete [] pic.data.RGB;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are `pic` and `SaveBitmapFile`?

Comment: `SaveBitmapFile` seems to be a Windows thing - I've added a Windows tag now.

Comment: @PaulR Nope, no a Windows-API function. You can do this on Linux as well as on Windows. But a complete example (using some other Windows-API functions) is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @harper: OK, thanks - my bad - I Googled `SaveBitmapFile` and got MSDN hits so assumed it was a Microsoft-ism. I'll remove the Windows tag and let the OP clarify.

Comment: The SaveBitmapFile is a funcktion i have created to save the data to a file.

Comment: You're not under the impression that the size of your `bit24` struct is actually 24 bits, are you?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley hmmp.. not quite sure actually.  though that I could  make my own type, since there is no 24 bit type, but i guess not :)

Comment: Use 3 chars (either an array of them, or three separate members).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley but the problem is that a char could be 24 bit or 32 bit right??

Comment: Theoretically? Yes. Realistically? Not on any platform that you are ever likely to care about. Anyone who does use such an exotic platform will probably avoid any libraries that weren't written specifically with that platform in mind, since so much code out there assumes 8 bit bytes.

Comment: Also, if a `char` *is* 32 bits (or any other size which doesn't evenly divide into 24), then you have no hope of creating a 24 bit type anyway, since `char` is, by definition, the smallest type, and the size of any other type is a multiple of that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley thank you for clearing that up :)

Comment: However, on second thought, it would probably be better to use a specifically sized type, either `int8_t` or `uint8_t`. First of all, it makes the intent more clear (you are using this data type specifically because it is 8 bits), and also, in the extremely unlikely event that someone *does* use your code on one of those exotic platforms, they will get a compiler error (because `(u)int8_t` will not be defined), instead of a non-working program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the problem.

After I changed  the bit24 to:

```
typedef struct{ 
uint8_t blue;
uint8_t green;
uint8_t red;
}RGB_Data;
```

from:

```
#pragma pack(1) 
typedef struct{
uint32_t value : 24;
}bit24;
#pragma pack(0)
```

and a little change in the main:

```
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < pic.data.Heigh * pic.data.Width * bytesPerRGB; i++){
    pic.data.RGB[i].blue  = b;
    pic.data.RGB[i].green = g;
    pic.data.RGB[i].red   = r;
}
```

it worked like a charm. thanx you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You MUST fill all BitmapInfoHeader fields.
- Assuming you want 24bits bitmap:

```
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi =
{
    sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), // DWORD, = 40
    WIDTH, // DWORD, image width in pix
    HEIGHT, // DWORD, image width in pix
    1, // WORD, planes MUST be 1
    24,// WORD, num of bits per pixel
    BI_RGB, // DWORD, (no compression = BI_RGB = 0)
    0, // DWORD, sizeof image data, can be 0 if BI_RGB = 0
    0, // DWORD, x-resolution
    0, // DWORD, y-resolution
    0, // DWORD, colors used (palette images only)
    0, // DWORD, importand colors (palette images only)
};
```

### Also make sure every row (horizontal line) of pixels is padded to multiple of 4 bytes !!!

(So begin with images of N x 4 width - they have no padding issues)

Comment: They are padded to multiple of 4 bytes. i even check for it and printing it out :)

Comment: Could you print out BitmapFileHeader & BitmapInfoHeader fields (VALUES) in your post? Or just binary dump of your file.